# refer to first link of particular div

Tags: jquery, attributes, refer

I have following elements:

```
<div class="content" id="content_1" style="display: none; ">

<ul class="ad-thumb-list" style="width: 473px; ">

<li> 
<a href="../images/portfolio/portfolio_1_1.png" class="ad-thumb0 ad-active">
<img src="../images/portfolio/thumbs/thumb_1_1.png"  style="opacity: 1; ">
</a>
</li>

    <li> 
<a href="../images/portfolio/portfolio_1_2.png" class="ad-thumb0">
<img src="../images/portfolio/thumbs/thumb_1_1.png"  style="opacity: 1; ">
</a>
</li>

  <li> 
<a href="../images/portfolio/portfolio_1_3.png" class="ad-thumb0">
<img src="../images/portfolio/thumbs/thumb_1_1.png"  style="opacity: 1; ">
</a>
  </li>         

 </ul>

</div>
```

I need to get href attribute of first link `<a>` inside `<ul> <li>`

I have several this kind of divs, as you can see it has id='content_1', so others will have id='content_2'... and so on.

How can I get href of first a in first li of a called div with jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#content_1 li:first a').attr('href');
```

if you have many divs, then:

```
$('.content').each( function() {
    $(this).find('li:first a').attr('href');
});
```

Comment: your code solved the issue, but I got last element clicked when I used $('#'+content_show+' ul.content_menu.tabs:first a').click(); and I changed it to $('#'+content_show+' ul.content_menu.tabs a').first().click(); then it clicked first element. what is difference btwn :first and first()

Answer (score 1):

The XPath to the `a` of interest would be:

```
//div[@id="content_1"]/ul/li[1]/a
```

Which means, anywhere below the root of the document find a `div` with the specified `id`. Under that, find a `ul` and get its first `li`. Inside that, there is an `a`.

How you actually achieve that in your case depends on what you're working with (client-side JS? one of the frameworks? web-scraping script?).

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention, I am using jQuery

Comment: I tried $("#"+content_show).find('a').attr('href')  and I tried $("#"+content_show+" ul li a").first().attr('href'); but it didn`t work